# Javascript scroll effect on a menu

Tags: javascript, octobercms

So I have a menu on a home page that has scroll effect to contact form.

```
<li><a href="{{ 'home'|page }}" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
```

And it works like a charm on the home page but if a user is on a different page, let say about or blog and clicks on Contact link she/he gets a redirect on a home page but scroll effect never takes place.

Is it possible to make that happen when a user is on a different page and clicks that link?

Code for scroll is:

```
$(function(){$(".scroll").click(function(){$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("#contact").offset().top},"500");return false})})
```

Console log after yezzz suggestion:

[image]

Comment: EDIT: oops misread... What's the url in the href after the page is rendered? They all point to example.com/#contact ?

Comment: Btw, that scroll script came with the theme? But you can modify it?

Answer (score 0):

If other pages are sending you to #contact on your homepage, then you could trigger the click:

```
$(function(){
    $(".scroll").click(function(){
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("#contact").offset().top},"500");
        return false;
    });
    if (window.location.hash == "#contact") $(".scroll").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Actually, that link leads just to a home page. October CMS doesn't have the best documentation so I don't know how to add #contact to {{ 'home'|page }}.

Comment: If the site is live can you give me the url?

Comment: Here it is. It is not finished so I will let it be live for 10-20 mins for you to check http://petfriendlyapp.com/

Comment: I only had a short chance to see it, but I see the above isn't gonna work. Linking to #contacts would also not scroll, but jump straight to #contacts. Can you put scripts on every page? Then you could pass an url parameter and read it on home page. Another way would be to check http referrer. Last option I can think of right now is use a cookie or localstorage to set a flag, then process it on homepage.

Comment: Script is on every page. Well I guess I'll have to think of some other way of doing it. too complicated. But thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah I can't think of any easy solution. Maybe look into window.open method.

Answer (score 0):

Well thought I 'd give it a shot using localstorage. Replace the default script (on all pages) with following and check your console for errors.

```
$(function(){
    $(".scroll").click(function(){
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("#contact").offset().top},"500");
        return false;
    });
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // localstorage is supported    
        if (location.pathname === "/") {
            // we're on homepage
            if (localStorage.triggerScroll == 1) {
                localStorage.triggerScroll = 0;
                $(".scroll").trigger("click");
            }
        } else {
        // we 're on another page
        $(".scroll").click(function(){
            localStorage.triggerScroll = 1;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code breaks my off-canvas menu so I can't even try it. Omg why is this so hard...

Comment: hmm I wouldn't know without seeing what happens. Did you get any error in the console?

Comment: you did see I edited the code some minutes after posting it?

Comment: I tried it one more time to be safe but my off canvas menu is still broken whit this code. I use Foundation 6 off canvas...

Comment: if there's no error in your log I wouldn't know what goes wrong, as it only reads/writes location and localstorage, and triggers the click on homepage.

Comment: I've updated initial post. There are plenty of errors unfortunately.

Comment: yeah sorry forget to close .click ... I edited my code... so try again

Comment: Still errors. I have to sleep over it. I will try to fix errors tomorrow. Thanks.